# Unable to run selenium webdriver script in IE11

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have IE 11 browser on Windows 8.
I'm trying to automate a simple search but I am getting an exception. (The script works in Firefox)

I made regedit changes according to instructions given in https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Created a QWORD value since I have 64 bit machine.

Following error appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

What else can I do to overcome this issue?

Comment: Did you search on stackoverflow. There are many people with the same issues.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712417/nosuchwindowexception-was-unhandled-unable-to-find-element-on-closed-window-i

Answer (score 1):

When I got the same error I edited settings in **Internet Explorer**:

> Tools -> Internet option -> Security

**Change security from high to medium-high or medium and UN-check Enable Protection Mode**

Second problem I found is:

[Sendkeys Working too Slow](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3072)

For this problem I used [IE 32 Bit Driver](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.45.0.zip)

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without seeing your code but a quick search on StackOverflow shows that people with similar error messages are having issues related to IE's Protected Mode ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330079/i-o-exception-and-unable-to-find-element-in-ie-using-selenium-webdriver)) or: `capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);`
([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746777/selenium-nosuchwindowexception-in-ie-11)).

Comment: However, manually setting the protected mode setting is recommended way than setting it from `capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);`